# best way to have a knex column search be optional

Tags: node.js, node-modules, knex.js

so far so good (or should i say "wonderful and excellent") using/learning knex.

i am trying to simulate the following condition to make a column name search optional:

```sql
AND tableName.columnNameOne = 2349
AND tableName.columnNameTwo = 'some value'
AND ( tableName.columnNameThree = 285 OR someFlag = true )
```

threre is an "undocumented feature" (love that expression!) of `.ofWhereRaw` that seems to work fine for what my requirements are:

```js
.andWhere({
  'tableName.columnNameOne': columnNameOneValue,
  'tableName.columnNameTwo': columnNameTwoValue,
}).andWhere((val) => {
  val.where({ 'tableName.columnNameThree': columnNameThreeValue });
  val.orWhereRaw('(true = ?)', columnNameThreeFlag);
});
```

Being a total newbie and recent convert to knex, is this the optional way to handle such a condition?   i get nervous using options that are not in the documentation since an undocumented option could be removed in a future release.

thank you very much, and thank you for knex (no more sequelize).

Comment: Do you have to have that flag in the sql query? Why not have it in JS?

Comment: i am trying to interface this with feathersJs - and passing a flag to "disable" one of the search options seemed like the easiest approach (but i could be wrong...)

Comment: Seems like you can do the flag in js. Make a query builder and then do `if (columnNameThreeFlag) { qb.andWhere(/* column three stuff */); }`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [`knex.raw`](https://knexjs.org/#Raw-Expressions) for your manual query parts.

```js
.andWhere({
  'tableName.columnNameOne': columnNameOneValue,
  'tableName.columnNameTwo': columnNameTwoValue,
}).andWhere((val) => {
  val.where({ 'tableName.columnNameThree': columnNameThreeValue });
  val.orWhere(knex.raw('true = ?', [columnNameThreeFlag]));
  // -----------^
});
```